# Haskell/Trifecta: Parsing completely optional semicolons without polluting AST

Tags: parsing, haskell, trifecta

### I have rewritten the question since it was originally posted with a more concise code example:

Consider a language with fully optional semicolons almost entirely as sugar, i.e.:

- `;; foo; bar;;;;` is valid
- `foo bar foobar` is valid
- `if (+1); foo` is different to `if (+1) foo` in semantics, so `;` cannot be considered whitespace

Here is an example parser:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Text.Trifecta
import Text.Trifecta.Delta
import Text.PrettyPrint.ANSI.Leijen (putDoc, (<>), linebreak)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict
import Control.Applicative

type TestParser a = StateT Int Parser a

data AST a = Foo a | Bar a deriving (Show)

pFoo :: TestParser (AST (Delta, Int))
pFoo = curry Foo <$ string "foo" <*> position <* modify (+1) <*> get

pBar :: TestParser (AST (Delta, Int))
pBar = curry Bar <$ string "bar" <*> position <*> get

pStmt :: TestParser (AST (Delta, Int))
pStmt = semi *> pStmt <|> pFoo <|> pBar <?> "statement"

pTest :: TestParser [AST (Delta, Int)]
pTest = some pStmt

main :: IO ()
main
 = do   let res = parseByteString (evalStateT pTest 0)
                    (Directed "(test)" 0 0 0 0) ";;foo;bar;\nfoo;; foobarbar;;"
        case res of
            Success ast
             -> print ast
            Failure errdoc
             -> putDoc (errdoc <> linebreak)
```

The problem I am having with such a parser is that I need to be able to skip over semicolons without committing to parse a `pStmt`. At the moment the following error occurs:

```
(test):2:18: error: unexpected
    EOF, expected: statement
foo;; foobarbar;;<EOF>
```

This is because it expects a statement (in `semi *> pStmt`), however because stacked semicolons can sugar both the beginning and end of expressions I can't be sure I really want to expect/parse one before I already expect one.

One hack I developed was to have `Nop` as a constructor in my AST, but I really don't want to do that -- it feels like a hack and with the number of semicolons in some documents it would greatly increase memory usage.

I am looking for solutions/suggestions.

---

Attempt at EBNF form of the desired grammar:

```
expr = "foo" | "bar"
expr with sugar = expr | ";"
program = { [white space], expr with sugar, [white space] }
```

Comment: Your parser seems to expect a statement *after* a semicolon. So as long as pure whitespace isn't a valid statement, there's no surprise that your parser complains about a semicolon at the end. If you want semicolons to terminate statements, why do you parse them at the beginning?

Comment: Because `;; if then { } ;;;` is completely valid, unfourtunately.

Comment: I changed it to `(semi *> (pStmt <|> (ANop <$> annotLoc)))` and the issue is resolved. This pollutes my AST with ANop though, and it kind of feels like a hack. Suggestions for a better way that doesn't feel like a hack are very welcome.

Comment: Updated the original question.

Comment: how about `pStmt = semi *> many semi *> pStmt ...` ?

Comment: If you do that you get `error: unexpected EOF` after the last semicolon if there is no statement (foo/bar) afterwards.

Comment: ok, 2 things: `pStmt = semi *> many semi *> pStmt ...` and `pTest = do {pS <- some pStmt; many semi; return pS }`

Comment: Same error. pStmt reads: `(semi *> many semi *> pStmt) <|> pFoo <|> pBar <?> "statement"` and pTest: `pTest = do {pS <- some pStmt; many semi; return pS }`

Comment: `pTest = do {many semi; pS <- some pStmt; many semi; return pS }` - we also parse semi in the beginning

Comment: I assume you mean to also change `main` to use `(some pTest)` then. It *almost* works! In fact, it does work, but now it won't throw a syntax error anymore if I put garbage in the test string.

Comment: Oh! It is need to add in the end parse EOF, like this:
`pTest = do {many semi; pS <- some pStmt; many semi; eof; return pS }`

Comment: Nope, it stops just before the `\n` with `error: expected: ;, end of input`. Close though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here it is:

```
pStmt = pFoo <|> pBar

pWhiteStmt = do
    many whitespace
    p <- pStmt
    many whitespace
    return p

pTest = do
    many semi
    pS <- sepEndBy pWhiteStm (some semi)
    eof
    return pS
```

And test it:

```
> parse pTest "" ";;foo;bar;\nfoo;; foo;bar;bar;;"
Right ["foo","bar","foo","foo","bar","bar"]

> parse pTest "" ";;foo;bar;\nfoo;; foobarbar;;"
Left (line 2, column 10):
unexpected 'b'
expecting ";" or end of input
```

If we wish to have a valid `"; foobarbar;"`, then we need to change `pWhiteStmt` parser to next:

```
pWhiteStmt = do
    many whitespace
    p <- some pStmt
    many whitespace
    return p
```

And check it:

```
> parse pTest "" ";;foo;bar;\nfoo;; foobarbar;;"
Right [["foo"],["bar"],["foo"],["foo","bar","bar"]]
```

And finally, if we still wish to have valid `"; foo  bar baz;"` then we also need to change `pTest` function to next:

```
pTest = do
    many semi
    pS <- sepEndBy (some pWhiteStm) (some semi)
    eof
    return pS
```

And test it

```
> parse pTest "" ";;foo;bar;\nfoo;; foo bar bar;;"
Right [[["foo"]],[["bar"]],[["foo"]],[["foo"],["bar"],["bar"]]]
```

If we have many parentheses , it is need to replace `return p` to `return (concat p)` in the `pWhiteStmt`